# Setting up Text Alignment (CTTextAligment) on NSAttributedString - ipad

Tags: ipad, uikit, core-text, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to draw a custom string with color, font, size and alignment.

I got everything working with an NSMutableAttributedString before, but it looks like Text Aligment only works with Paragraph alignement which only works with non mutable version of NSString.

So, I had to change my previous code to this :

```
    //Note : _name variables are provided by my GUI for text, size and font name.

    //Create the String ColorRef
    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    const CGFloat myColor[] = {_color.r/255.0, _color.g/255.0, _color.b/255.0, 1.0f};
    CGColorRef colorRef = CGColorCreate(rgb, myColor);

    //Setup paragraph Alignment Ref
    CTTextAlignment theAlignment = kCTCenterTextAlignment;
    CFIndex theNumberOfSettings = 1;
    CTParagraphStyleSetting theSettings[1] = {{ kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &theAlignment }};
    CTParagraphStyleRef theParagraphRef = CTParagraphStyleCreate(theSettings, theNumberOfSettings);

    //Prep Font
    NSDictionary *fontAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: _fontName, (NSString *)kCTFontFamilyNameAttribute,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_fontSize], (NSString *)kCTFontSizeAttribute,
                                    nil];
    CTFontRef font = [self newFontWithAttributes:fontAttributes];

    //Prepare String Attributes
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: (id)font, (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_fontSize], (NSString *)kCTFontSizeAttribute,
                                                                 (id)theParagraphRef, (NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, 
                                                                            colorRef, (NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    //Create the Attributed String
    NSAttributedString *myString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textString
                                                                   attributes: attributes];
```

But the Text Aligment still doesn't work. Everything else is fine but text remains aligned on the Left.

Why ?

EDIT :
Each of my strings are created inside a class that is a subclass of CATextLayer. Each of those TextLayers are then added to a CALayer as sublayers. On updates I apply trasformation matrix on the sublayers and use `setNeedsDisplay`. This is how I display the text on screen. Maybe There's a reason here why the CTParagraphStyleRef set is not working ?

Comment: How are you drawing the string?

Comment: And what leads you to believe that “Paragraph alignement … only works with non mutable version of NSString”?

Comment: Are you using a type setter and doing manual linebreaks?

Comment: @RobNapier MyObject is a subclass of CATextLayer and all AttStrings are added to a CALayer object. I also apply transformation on ctx in drawInContext method.

Comment: @PeterHosey I don't know....I've read it on some post I guess. And I haven't found any pragraph object or methods in documentation or online in general...

Comment: @oberthelot: Depends on what you mean by “paragraph object”. Objects for controlling the alignment, etc. of paragraphs are instances of CTParagraphStyle. There is no object for a paragraph of text; Core Text lays out text in lines within a frame, where a frame can contain any number of paragraphs.

Comment: @oberthelot: Please edit your question to include the code that creates the CATextLayer and passes the text to it, along with any code you've added in your subclass for drawing the text.

Comment: Found it ! Silly of me not to have notice that there's a alignmentMode in the CATextLayer...I don't really know why the paragraphStyle I've set is not working though...But I found another way to make it work ! Thanks to all of you for pointing the way !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no clues why the ParagraphStyle that I've set is not working, But I've found a solution that's working for me, so I'm posting it in case someone encounter similar problems :

- My class is subclassing CATextLayer, which I think would've been important to mention in my question (my bad, I'll edit it).
- Inside my CATextLayer class, I create the string using the code
  shown in my question.
- Then I use the `self.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;` to align
  the text the way I want.
- Each string is then added to a CALAyer for display

I've also found this [very good guide on AttributedStrings](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/03/attributed-strings-in-ios.html) that helped me improving my code and finding this solution.